# JQuery autocomplete with using handler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, autocomplete, handler

I' m trying to create a search box with autocomplete property and using a handler.
I got all words from database but can not show them.

It' s jquery part:

```
$(function () {
    $("#search-box").autocomplete({
        source: "KeywordHandler.ashx",
        minLength: 1,
        @*select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.id + " / " + ui.item.value);
        }*@
    });
});
```

It' s handler part:

```
public class KeywordHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["term"];
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSN"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "select Keyword from [dbo].[Log] where " + "Keyword like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        sb.Append(sdr["Keyword"])
                            .Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

At handler, I can get all the words which I need but can not show them as offered keywords at search box.

Is there any idea?

Comment: It looks you are not fetching the string in true format. Did you try using JSON? Please check the returning string from your function. So, you can use my answer (parsing JSON).

Comment: Hi Josh, maybe you are right but I solved with another way. You can see the answer below. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like below. Pay attention to "refresh" part. You should return your query result as JSON from webservice and then parse it. After parse, you can create list item for every search result item as I indicated in JQuery code (the last part of the code).

*I wrote my answer as supposing you are getting the result from your service properly.

HTML

```
<div id="assignDiv" style="display:none;">
                <div data-demo-html="true" data-demo-js="true" data-demo-css="true">
                    <h3>Select contact:</h3>                    
                    <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search contact..." data-filter-theme="d"></ul>
                </div>

                <input type="button" value="Send to selected contact" id="assignToBtn" />
            </div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#autocomplete").on("listviewbeforefilter", function (e, data) {
        var $ul = $(this),
            $input = $(data.input),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html("");
        if (value && value.length > 2) {
            $ul.html("<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>");
            $ul.listview("refresh");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                url: serverAddress + "General.asmx/AutoComplete",
                data: "{'q': '" + $input.val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                var JsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);

                $.each(JsonObj, function (i, val) {
                    html += "<li><a href='javascript:changeAutoCompleteText(\"" + val + "\");'>" + val + "&nbsp;<i style='color:grey;font-weight:lighter;'>(</i><i style='text-decoration:underline;color:grey;font-weight:lighter;'>" + val + "</i><i style='color:grey;font-weight:lighter;'>)</i></a></li>";
                });
                $ul.html(html);
                $ul.listview("refresh");
                $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
```